# HTML div with img in it displaying strangely

Tags: css, image, html

On the website I'm working on ([this](http://rwzimage.com/albums/)), I have a div with an img in it. This is the html

```
<div><overlay> <img class="img1" height="225" src="NYC/wtc1.JPG" width="225" /></overlay</div>

<div><overlay> <img class="img2" height="225" src="NYC/wtcmem.jpg" width="225" /></overlay></div>

<div><overlay> <img class="img3" height="225" src="NYC/sky.jpg" width="225" /></overlay></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

nothing too complicated. This is the CSS for the classes `img1`, `img2`, and `img3`.

```
.img1
{
position:absolute;
left:12%;
}
.img2
{
display:block;
margin:auto;
}
.img3
{
position:absolute;
right:12%;
}
```

also pretty simple. But, if you look at the website, the 3rd image (at least for me on Safari) is much lower than the other two. Why would this happen? I don't see anything in the CSS or HTML that would cause this.

Comment: `overlay` is a CSS element that becomes a translucent white when it is hovered on.

Comment: What is a CSS element?

Comment: I may not know the terminology exactly, I'm sorta new to CSS.

Comment: CSS doesn't have elements, HTML does.  There is no such thing as an `<overlay>` element in HTML.

Comment: Or, for that matter, a `<margin>` element.

Comment: Out of curiosity then, why does it work when I put those as HTML elements?

Comment: Define 'work'.  What default styles will these elements have?  What ARIA roles will they take on?  They work in the sense that browsers will handle most crap you throw at them, they appear in the DOM and you can apply CSS to them, but you're [not writing HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frwzimage.com%2Falbums%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: @robertc Thanks for pointing all this out, my HTML could obviously use some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some markup like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div><img class="img1" height="225" src="http://rwzimage.com/albums/NYC/wtc1.JPG" width="225" /></div>
    <div><img class="img2" height="225" src="http://rwzimage.com/albums/NYC/wtcmem.jpg" width="225" /></div>
    <div><img class="img3" height="225" src="http://rwzimage.com/albums/NYC/sky.jpg" width="225" /></div>
</div>
```

Then I think this CSS will have approximately the effect you're after:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 960px;
}

.wrapper > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > div:hover img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/t7AVU/).  I set `width: 960px;` so that it would force things to be wider than the JSFiddle window, but you could set `width: 100%;` for your page.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to do the best I can with your code, the following will work for you:

```
<div class="container" style="overflow:hidden; text-align:center;">
<div style="display:inline-block; margin: 0px 80px;">
    <div class="overlay">
        <img class="img1" height="225" src="NYC/wtc1.JPG" width="225">
    </div>
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block; margin: 0px 80px;">
    <div class="overlay">
        <img class="img2" height="225" src="NYC/wtcmem.jpg" width="225">
    </div>
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block; margin: 0px 80px;">
    <div class="overlay">
        <img class="img3" height="225" src="NYC/sky.jpg" width="225">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Note that `<overlay>` is not a valid HTML element. also I've seen on the page you used something like `<margin>`. It's not a good practice to invent HTML elements.. You can get all the functionality you need using regular `<div>`s (although I don't think this will break your page.. maybe only in older browsers..).

What I basically did:

1. Wrapped the three `<div>`s with a container with `text-align:center`. This will make the three divs inside it aligned to the center.
2. Added `display:inline-block;` to make all the divs follow the text-align.
3. Added margins to the divs to space them

Note that I **strongly recommend** to replace your `<overlay>` with something like `<div class="overlay">`

Comment: This fixed the problem, but how can I center the 2nd div?

Answer (score 0):

`div` tag naturally stack vertically.  So you will need to add an id to each `div` or you could just put all the `img` in one `div`.

The `block` css attribute is effecting the layout.  It is pushing the next `img` to the next line.

Comment: What difference will having an `id` make to the layout?

Comment: if you apply an `id` to each `div` then you can reference them in the CSS directly.  Allowing you to control position and layout of the `div` instead of the `img` tags.

Comment: You can reference them directly without an `id`, that's what things like `:nth-child()` do.